# hline inside a TikZ node

Tags: tikz-pgf, automata

How can I draw a horizontal line inside a TikZ node? 
I want the name of the state to be seperated from the rest of the node. How can i achieve this?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{automata}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    every node/.style={%
        align=center,
        state
    }    
]

    \node (T0)  {
        \textbf{State$_1$} \\  
        \hline \\ % <--- This is not working!
        $\overline{A}$      \\ 
        $B$
    };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Either put them inside a tabular or use TikZ for **drawing** things inside a TikZ picture.

Comment: You could just use `\underline{\textbf{State$_1$}}`.  What is the `\hline` supposed to do? Draw a line from one end of the circle to the other? In that case use multi part nodes.

Comment: You could use `\node[circle split]` and divide both parts with `\nodepart{lower}`. This will generate a split-circle node with everything in the upper half, except for the stuff after the `\nodepart{lower}` command. — Nicolás was a few seconds quicker than me … :D

Comment: Only a couple of seconds quicker.

Comment: You are all awesome. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try `circle split`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{automata,shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    every node/.style={%
        align=center,
        state,
        circle split
    }    
]

\node (T0)  {
    \textbf{State$_1$} \\
    \nodepart{lower}
    $\overline{A}$      \\ 
    $B$
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The keys are:

1. adding to the style `circle split`
2. drawing the separator as `\nodepart{lower}` instead of `\hline`

One drawback of this method is that the split line is drawn exactly at the middle of the circle. I don't know if that bothers you.

Comment: Yes. Excatly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In TikZ the hline is not defined (as far as i know). If i correctly understood, what you like to achieve, then for node use shape for multiple text parts, like in the following example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2pt]{standalone}
    \usetikzlibrary{automata,shapes.multipart}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
    every node/.style = {%
        align=center,
        state
    }
                        ]
\node[circle split] (T0)  { \textbf{State$_1$} \\
                    \nodepart{lower}
                            $\overline{A}$     \\
                            $B$
                          };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes thanks. That's excatly what I was looking for!